# Adding custom behavior to all repositories without xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to add custom behavior to all repositories in my spring application but **I don't want to use XML configuration**, only spring annotation like `@xxxx`.

So I looked for that on the Internet and I found [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).
The problem with the documentation is that it deals with JPA (not MongoDB) and the step 4 is not specific enough for a spring application without xml annotation.

#### Documentation step 4 :

> declare beans of the custom factory directly

How we do that?

So I didn't give up and I looked deeper on the Internet and I found [this](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/solr/spring-data-solr-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-to-all-repositories/).

But this time, it was for Solr (not Mongo).
The interesting part is:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.solr.repository.config.EnableSolrRepositories;

@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(
    basePackages = "net.petrikainulainen.spring.datasolr.todo.repository.solr",
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomSolrRepositoryFactoryBean.class
)
public class SolrContext {

  //Configuration is omitted.
}
```

But my application still does not work! You can find all the code in [github](http://github.com/youtix/add_custom_behavior_to_all_repositories_without_xml_annotation).

#### Architecture

```
src/main/java
fr.exemple.test.Application.java
fr.exemple.test.controller.TestController.java
fr.exemple.test.model.domain.Test.java
fr.exemple.test.model.repository.TestRepository.java
fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global.MyRepository.java
fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global.MyRepositoryFactoryBean.java
fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global.MyRepositoryImpl.java
```

#### My Code

Application :

```
package fr.exemple.test;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global.MyRepositoryFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoRepositories(
    basePackages = {"fr.exemple.test.repository.global"},
    repositoryFactoryBeanClass = MyRepositoryFactoryBean.class
)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);
        app.run(args);
    }
}
```

TestController :

```
package fr.exemple.test.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import fr.exemple.test.model.repository.TestRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestRepository repository;


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void sharedCustomMethodTest() {
        repository.sharedCustomMethod("Hello World !");
    }
}
```

Test :

```
package fr.exemple.test.model.domain;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Test {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Test() {}

    public Test(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

}
```

TestRepository :

```
package fr.exemple.test.model.repository;

import fr.exemple.test.model.domain.Test;
import fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global.MyRepository;

public interface TestRepository extends MyRepository<Test, String> {

}
```

MyRepository :

```
package fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.NoRepositoryBean;

@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID>{

    void sharedCustomMethod(ID id);
}
```

MyRepositoryFactoryBean :

```
package fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.BasicMongoPersistentEntity;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoPersistentEntity;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MappingMongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.RepositoryMetadata;
import org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport;
import org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation;
import org.springframework.data.util.TypeInformation;

public class MyRepositoryFactoryBean<R extends MongoRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable>
    extends MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I> {

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport getFactoryInstance(MongoOperations operations) {
        return new MyRepositoryFactory<T, I>(operations);
    }

    private static class MyRepositoryFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends
            MongoRepositoryFactory {

        private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

        public MyRepositoryFactory(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
            super(mongoOperations);
            this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
        }

        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            TypeInformation<T> information =  ClassTypeInformation.from((Class<T>)metadata.getDomainType());
            MongoPersistentEntity<T> pe = new BasicMongoPersistentEntity<T>(information);
            MongoEntityInformation<T,I> mongometa = new MappingMongoEntityInformation<T, I>(pe);
            return new MyRepositoryImpl<T, I>(mongometa, mongoOperations);
        }

        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return MyRepository.class;
        }
    }
}
```

MyRepositoryImpl :

```
package fr.exemple.test.model.repository.global;

import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoEntityInformation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository;

public class MyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends
    SimpleMongoRepository<T, ID> implements MyRepository<T, ID> {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MyRepositoryImpl.class);
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public MyRepositoryImpl(MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata,
        MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public void sharedCustomMethod(ID id) {
        log.info(id);
    }
}
```

#### Stack Trace

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enabled debug logging (start with --debug)

2014-07-13 11:12:51.951 ERROR 2144 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.exemple.test.model.repository.TestRepository fr.exemple.test.controller.TestController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at fr.exemple.test.Application.main(Application.java:23)


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.exemple.test.model.repository.TestRepository fr.exemple.test.controller.TestController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 14 common frames omitted



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 16 common frames omitted



Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:213)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:321)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:301)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:82)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:52)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:128)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:320)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 26 common frames omitted




Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.exemple.test.model.repository.TestRepository fr.exemple.test.controller.TestController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at fr.exemple.test.Application.main(Application.java:23)



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.exemple.test.model.repository.TestRepository fr.exemple.test.controller.TestController.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 14 more



Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 16 more



Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property shared found for type void!
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:213)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:321)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:301)
at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:82)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:52)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:128)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:320)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
... 26 more
```

Comment: Since this is a Spring Boot project, shouldn't you also annotate `Application` with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens as the package structure is not consistent. The base package of `@EnableMongoRepositories` points to `fr.exemple.test.repository.global` whereas the repository definition is located in `fr.exemple.test.model.repository`. As the scan for repositories returns without any result boot auto configuration, at this point not knowing of any custom RepositoryFactoryBean definitions, kicks in, enabling repositories on `fr.exemple.test` where `Application` resides.

So you could update your package structure.
Or make boot aware of `MyRepositoryFactoryBean` by registering it in your context via `@Component` and remove `@EnableMongoRepositories` so that [scanning for](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/55650bd61887cbfddabbb5167acbf9121682d7fe/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.java#L56) a bean of type `RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport` can pick up the config.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `@EnableMongoRepositories` please take a look at availables options. One of them is :

`public abstract Class<?> repositoryFactoryBeanClass`

Returns the FactoryBean class to be used for each repository instance.

Defaults to MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.

Returns:
Default:
`org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.class`

so i.e

`@EnableMongoRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass=YourMongoCustomRepositoryFactoryBean.class)`